# Elasticsearch index attachments without storing the encoded file

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using elasticsearch-mapper-attachments and I am able to index and search for text within attachments, however I have a lot of pdfs which are mainly images, and I was wondering if it's possible to configure ES to not store the base64 encoded file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. During the index creation specify
"_source": { "compress": "true", "excludes" : ["file"] },